# Differential Equation of 2nd degree with non constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation :

$x''+tx'+x=0$

I tried variable change but no results. Is there a concrete way that works for every equation of this kind. If you can show me step by step that would be great.

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $tx'+x=(tx)'$ and so:$$x''+tx'+x=0\\(x'+tx)'=0\\x'+tx=C$$Can you solve this simple linear first-order equation now?